# Why this flatness condition is needed? (Serge lang's Algebra)(p.618, chapter 16, proposition 3.7)

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, flatness

[image]

[My Question] Why "$F$ is flat is needed in this proof?

[My attempt]

Let $f : \mathcal{a} \otimes F \rightarrow \mathcal{a}F $ be defined by $f(\sum_i x_i \otimes b_i) = \sum_ix_i b_i$ . (By universal property, this map exists)

Also let $g : \mathcal{a}F  \rightarrow \mathcal{a} \otimes F $ be defined by $g(\sum_ix_i b_i) = \sum_i x_i \otimes b_i$ .

Then I think $f \circ g = i_d$ and $ g \circ f = i_d$ ,so they are isomorphic.

Where is the problem in this proof?

Thanks.

Comment: You should carefully check that those maps are isos.

Comment: $g$ does not exists in general. Your definition depends on the $x_i$ and $b_i$ chosen.

Comment: @A.G you're right! thank you